# application does not handle SIGTERM an azure AKS

Tags: kubernetes, nestjs, azure-aks, sigterm

I have a containerized NestJS application. If I run it locally using docker, I can shut it down gracefully which I can see via logging. If I run the same container on AKS, there is no log output about shutting down on pod deletion. The pod rather stay in state Terminating for half a minute and is then deleted.

If I execute a shell inside the container on AKS, a `ps` shows me, that my application is running with PID 1. If I send a SIGTERM to PID 1 using `kill -15 1`, the application does neither log the signal, nor does it shut down while becoming unresponsive at the same time.

```bash
/app $ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 node      0:03 node main.js
   18 node      0:00 sh
   25 node      0:00 ps
/app $ kill -15 1
/app $ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 node      0:03 node main.js
   18 node      0:00 sh
   27 node      0:00 ps
```

If I do the same with the same container using docker locally, my application logs the received signal and shuts down.

```bash
/app $ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 node      0:03 node main.js
   18 node      0:00 sh
   25 node      0:00 ps
/app $ kill -15 1
/app $ <shell exited here as container was removed by docker>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please refer to the official documentation from kubernetes - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#hook-details
The preStop Hook is a special command that is sent to the containers in the pod.
If your application doesn’t gracefully shut down when receiving a SIGTERM you can use this hook to trigger a graceful shutdown. Most programs gracefully shut down when receiving a SIGTERM, but if you are using third-party code or are managing a system you don’t have control over, the preStop hook is a great way to trigger a graceful shutdown.

Comment: It should look something like this-
lifecycle:
        preStop:
          exec:
            command: ["sleep", "15"]

You can refer to this example- https://learnk8s.io/graceful-shutdown

Comment: Well the issue is, that my app handles the SIGTERM correctly inside a container running via docker on my laptop while the same application running from the same image in a pod on azure AKS does not seem to receive the SIGTERM.